# Нужно увеличить счет при правильном ответе

Tags: python, python-3.x

господа прогеры, помогите, пожалуйста,начинающему решить проблему, ответ на которую не получается найти в инете.

**Суть проблемы:** нужно увеличить счет после каждого верного ответа пользователя и сохранять его с каждым началом новой игры, до того как пользователь не прервет ее, отказавшись от предложения продолжить.

**Мой код:**

```
import random

def game():
    score = 0
    choice = 'д'
    while choice == 'д':
        secret = random.randint(0,10)
        
        guess = int(input("Угадай число от 1 до 10: "))
        if guess == secret:
            print("Верно! Это было число ", secret)
            score += 1
            print("Твой счет: ", score)
            choice = input("Продолжить игру? (д\н): ")
            if choice == 'д':
                game()
            else:
                print("Спасибо за участие! Ты закончил игру со счетом: ", score)
        elif guess < secret:
            print("Твое число меньше загаданного")
            game()

        elif guess > secret:
            print("Твое число больше загаданного")
            game()
```

Comment: Просто уберите рекурсивные вызовы game и вставьте break после "Спасибо за участие"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При текущем скрипте при неправильном вводе цифра меняется, попробуй так:

```
import random


def game():
    score = 0
    choice = 'д'
    secret = random.randint(1, 10)
    while choice == 'д':
        
        guess = int(input("Угадай число от 1 до 10: "))
        if guess == secret:
            print("Верно! Это было число ", secret)
            score += 1
            print("Твой счет: ", score)
            choice = input("Продолжить игру? (д\н): ")
            secret = random.randint(1, 10)
            if choice != 'д':
                print("Спасибо за участие! Ты закончил игру со счетом: ", score)
                break
        elif guess < secret:
            print("Твое число меньше загаданного")

        elif guess > secret:
            print("Твое число больше загаданного")
```